# Request to Random.org API with ZendFramework2

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I'm quite new to ZF2 and I wanted to create some app utilizing external API. I have successfully created method to send requests to random.org API but as a response it sends me an error connected with parsing. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and how to improve my method to get proper data in response.

Here is my method used to send request (I have intentionally changed api key and in my app I'm using the proper one):

```
public function makeRequest()
{
    $data = array(
        'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
        'method' => 'generateIntegers',
        'params' => array(
            'apiKey' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
            'n' => 10,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 10,
            'replacement' => true,
            "base" => 10),
        'id' => 23866,
    );

    $client = new Client('https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke', array(
        'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl'
    ));
    $client->setEncType(Client::ENC_FORMDATA);

    $request = new Request();
    $request->setUri('https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke');
    $request->setMethod('POST');
    $request->getPost()->fromString(json_encode($data));
    $response = $client->send($request);

    return $response;
}
```

And here is the content of response:

```
["content":protected]=> string(87) "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error","data":null},"id":null}
```

Comment: What did you try to get by using getPost()->fromString?

Comment: I was trying to utilize this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19562830/4409736

Comment: And random.org requires passed data to be a JSON so I used this method to pass a JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [ZF2 Request Reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.http.request.html), you can find `setContent()` function, could you try that instead of `getPost()->fromString()`?

```
public function makeRequest()
{
    $data = array(
        'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
        'method' => 'generateIntegers',
        'params' => array(
            'apiKey' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
            'n' => 10,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 10,
            'replacement' => true,
            "base" => 10),
        'id' => 23866,
    );

    $client = new Client('https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke', array(
        'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl'
    ));
    $client->setEncType(Client::ENC_FORMDATA);

    $request = new Request();
    $request->setUri('https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke');
    $request->setMethod('POST');


    //$request->getPost()->fromString(json_encode($data));
    $request->setContent(json_encode($data));

    $response = $client->send($request);

    return $response;
}
```